# how to make javax.ws post request similar to postman request?

Tags: java, http, postman, javax.ws.rs

I try to send an http post request with postman and it works
(it works using `curl` as well)

I get a positive response

[image]

I try to do the same request in code using

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;



        Map<String, String> formData = new HashMap();
        formData.put("update_type", "config");
        formData.put("role", role);
        formData.put("name", configNameCamelCase);
        formData.put("version", version);
        formData.put("work_env", env);
        formData.put("project", "waze-prod");
        formData.put("provider", "gce");


        try {
            String a = commonClient.webTarget
                    .path("/tasks/update_version")
                    .request()
                    .header("Authorization", commonClient.authorizedRequestBuilder())
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE)
                    .post(Entity.entity(formData, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                    .readEntity(String.class);
}
```

How should i change my code to make it identical to the postman request

Comment: why downovte? please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Form`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Form.html) and just add parameters with `Form#param(key, value)`. Then use `.post(Entity.form(form))`.

```
Form form = new Form()
  .param("one", "two")
  .param("three", "four");

...post(Entity.form(form));
```

Comment: what do you mean by `Form#param` ? how is the java syntax?

Comment: Create an instance of `Form` and call `param` on it to add values